# Trigger dependent Jenkins job at specific time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 jobs called job A and job B.
If Job A is built successfully I want to trigger job B next day at 8 am.

How can I put condition to build trigger ?

Comment: using pipeline or freestyle job?

Comment: Freestyle job...

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by querying the upstream job with an intermediate job. The intermediate job is scheduled at 8am and queries job A using the Jenkins API to find out when it last run and triggers B if it has run in the last 24 hours.

Comment: How to query upstream job?

Comment: Now my requirement is to Build Job B after 24 hours of the latest build from Job A

Answer (score 0):

We have parent job that triggers the child job only on success, after one hour of the completion of the parent job. In order to postpone the execution of the child job, we have specified a quiet time in the child job - this is a time measured in seconds that the job waits to be executed.

For more details about the setup in Jenkins, you could see [this 1-minute youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhYDHzltW2o).